# Why is the unzip with WinRAR so slow?

Tags: performance, zip, winrar

Why is the unzip so slow, if the processor is not 100% busy, disk I/O is not saturated, and there is enough memory?

I'm using Win7 x64, but this was just an example. (The package can be anything big enough to measure the time).

Why doesn't the decompression use 100% CPU if there is something to do (or 50% with two cores, doesn't matter)?

Comment: What software do you use for unzipping, and what format is the file? deflate, winzip, pkzip and 7zip are all "unzipped".

Comment: @Eroen using winrar and format is .zip

Comment: Are you running a virus scanner or something that may be interfering?

Answer (score 2):

Check the multithreading option in WinRAR settings and uncheck Low priority option.

Make sure you are running the latest version of WinRAR or just use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I have also been experiencing delays with WinRAR under Win10, unclear what Windows Processes or Services are contributing factors but the User OOBE Broker seems to be a likely candidate.  Had WinRAR stalling completely until I hand-killed a number of Windows auto-update services & the OOBE broker process.

6.11 does not have a multithreading option, I presume that means it's baked-in.  Running an 8-core, 16-thread Ryzen7 2700 with only 16% of 32GB RAM in use so there's plenty of resources for WinRAR to make use of.

[WinRAR 6.11 options screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e76g2.png)

I am also using SilverAzide's CPU Meter under Rainmeter with HWInfo64.  Running a Benchmark test loads out the CPU near 90%, but when actually opening files with WinRAR, it runs very slowly & can't hit even 10% CPU utilization.  Checking "All Cores mode" only shows a few cores momentarily used at 17% or less during the entire operation.

It certainly appears that actual runtime Multithreading is either missing or horribly mis-implemented in the 6.11 published build.

Comment: Top left, number of threads in screenshot you shared, yet you say NO multithreading option? I also fail to see how this is an answer in sense of solution to problem.